# How can I use system icons in my android app?

Tags: android, icons

I am programming an android application and I'd like to use the system icons for mail, phone, calendar and contacts inside this application. The problem is, that these icons differ from system to system (different android versions and different smartphones) and I want to keep the application and the system consistent. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand, you want to use system resources, but you want the resources to be the same no matter the system?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In XML use default android drawables from  @android:drawable/... and in code use android.R.drawable....

Answer (score 6):

You can use the standard drawable using 
@android:drawable/[icon_name] in your xml file
android.R.drawable.[icon_name] in your java code

You can see different icon in your file system in 
[SDK PATH]/platforms/platforms/[ANDROID_VERSION]/data/res

Some images are standard...like contacts, calendar :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't keep system consistent. For what? New versions of Android are usually prettier than older ones (well, it's my opinion).

The only way to keep system icons same for your app - copy them into your drawables instead of using direct reference to them (like `@android:drawable/`).

Answer (score 4):

First of all if you intend to use the default images (icons) for mail , phonr etc.

This default can be used as android.R.drawable.name in code or @android:drawable/ in xml from `http://docs.since2006.com/android/2.1-drawables.php`

But as this will vary from OS versinos to Versions.

So , if you need to use an unique GUI for the app for all versions and devices.

Please do not use android provided images , simply use your own graphics or images supplied in drawables resources explicitly by you for your app.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with icons from each system you can get it via PackageManager and getApplicationInfo method.

If you're not, you should copy the resources from the platform into your own application.